# TeamCity no longer running Protractor/Jasmine test via Gulp

Tags: gulp, jasmine, protractor

Had a successful test suite running under TeamCity (Protractor/Jasmine/JS). However we are now no longer able to get beyond the first build step

```
npm install
```

After trying to start the test suite, very quickly, build step two fails. This is gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var gulpProtractorAngular = require("gulp-angular-protractor");

 gulp.task("runtest", callback => {
 gulp
    .src(["SmokeTest.js"])
    .pipe(gulpProtractorAngular({
        configFile: "SmokeTest.js",
        debug: false,
        autoStartStopServer: true
    }))
    .on("error", e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
    .on("end", callback);
});
```

The only change between a working state and now is that we've added a few more specs. The whole suite runs just fine locally.

I've downloaded the Build Log from a successful run and a fail and the ONLY difference - apart from the error notification, is a message:

```
    [Step 2/3] [Step 2/3] [17:31:06] The following tasks did not complete: runtest
    [Step 2/3] [17:31:06] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

So the *gulpfile.js* might be the culprit but I don't  understand why or how to make a change to fix!

Help please!